# Delphi: horz scrollbar hides, instead of being shown as I tell

Tags: delphi, winapi

I use Delphi7 / Win XP SP3 / [TMemo-like control](http://econtrol.ru) TSyntaxMemo.

I change code of control horz scrollbar setting. I call

- `SetScrollInfo` with `si.fMask := SIF_ALL or SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL;`
- `ShowScrollBar` with `bShow := not FWordWrapState`

I then see that for WordWrap ON horz-bar hides as needed, but for WordWrap OFF it doesn't show as needed! It may show or may not, it depends on SetScrollInfo parameters somehow.

Is it a known issue?

Comment: I suggest you ask the author of the component. We don't have the source code. It's quite possibly not a windows `EDIT` control. What makes you think that it is?

Comment: So what are you looking for from us? We cannot reproduce what you observe. What's wrong with my answer to your other question. Is there anything more that anyone could say? The only person that could do more I suspect it the author of the component, or you (since you are the only one with the project).

Comment: @D.H., maybe it's SyntMemo issue, but maybe it's known bug of WinAPI. I have another project, based on other control (TPanel as parent), and horz scrollbar disappears there when i adjust it. Maybe the same WINAPI issue.

Comment: FYI [there *is* a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66325028/653473) that is related `SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL`, which causes the scroll bars to not be shown as they should be. It sounds like it may be related.